# How to create custom taxonomy where I can select category for that particular taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I need to add category selection for custom taxonomy.

For example, I have two category called "Cricket and Football". And I have custom taxonomy called player. When I add player like "abc" at that time I need to select sports like cricket or football.

How can I manage this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this line in the arguments for your custom post type:

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
```

It is likely that you may already have this line in the existing code for your custom post type with some other custom taxonomy in it. If you do, then you just need to add a comma after that and add a category, like this:

```
'taxonomies' => array('other_tax', 'category' ),
```

Here is a full example of code to create a custom post type called ‘Player’ with support for built-in categories.

```
    function custom_post_type() {
     
        $labels = array(
            'name'                => 'Players',
            'singular_name'       => 'Player',
            'menu_name'           => 'Players',
            'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Player',
            'all_items'           => 'All Players',
            'view_item'           => 'View Player',
            'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Player',
            'add_new'             => 'Add New',
            'edit_item'           => 'Edit Player',,
            'update_item'         => 'Update Player',
            'search_items'        => 'Search Player',
            'not_found'           => 'Not Found',
            'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
        );
         
    // Set other options for Custom Post Type
         
        $args = array(
            'label'               => 'player',
            'description'         => 'sports people',
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-universal-access',
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'page',
            'show_in_rest'        => true,
             
            // This is where we add taxonomies to the CPT
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
        );
         
        // Registering your Custom Post Type
        register_post_type( 'player', $args );
     
    }

 
/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/
 
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: I don't want to create custom post type. I want custom taxonomy where i can select category for that taxonomy.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend using the ACF plugin - You will be able to add a field to your custom taxonomy and select categories there - that's the easiest way to accomplish what you're after imho. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, i can add category for taxonomy that way. But i also want that category slug in permalink when i open any taxonomy on frontend.
Like: domian.com/cricket/player/virat
-> Here cricket is category and player is custom taxonomy.

Comment: I would make all three categories, or the same custom taxonomy (to achieve the desired url structure) and then check if top parent (or look for a custom field) to serve the right type of page to visitors